# scipy.signal.wiener always show warning

Tags: python, filter, scipy, noise-reduction

I'm trying to use the wiener denoise function from Scipy in a grayscale image:

```
image = data.imread(image_path, as_grey=True)
image = signal.wiener(image)
```

but I always get this warning:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/signal/signaltools.py:425: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
      res *= (1 - noise / lVar)
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/signal/signaltools.py:425: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
      res *= (1 - noise / lVar)
```

The filter works fine, but why I get this warning?

Comment: I can reproduce those warnings if all the values in `image` are the same, e.g. `wiener(np.ones((24, 24)))`.  Is that the case with your input?

Comment: Actually, the array doesn't have to be constant.  I also get warnings with `wiener(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(24, 24))`.

Comment: No.. it isn't the case.

Comment: This bug looks to be related: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert the data type of input image to float32 or float64, that is:

```
image = image.astype('float64')
image = signal.wiener(image)
```

I guess we countered the "divided by zero" as the underflow number.